# Changing the image I see when installing my own watch face

Tags: ios, pebble-watch, cloudpebble

Currently, I have a new watchface and when I load it into the iOS application, I see a square with white noise. How can i change it to add a screenshot of my application?

Thus, when I have two applications I have created I cannot distinguish them unless I read the name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Android, but your description sounds exactly like what I experienced there.

I don't think there's any way to get a useful screenshot in the Pebble app without [publishing your app](https://dev-portal.getpebble.com/). During this process you will need to provide at least one screenshot.

After you publish, the Pebble app should show your screenshot even when you're working on new versions that you install locally.

This *might* work even if you add your app to the Pebble app store *but don't publish it*. I think the trick is getting screenshots in the store that match your app's UUID.

Answer (score 0):

If coding the app in cloud pebble under your projects settings there is a Menu Image setting that lets you upload a .PNG for use.